# Sync issue with Chrome, the page stuck at 'Processing request...'

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser

I am having multiple problems on my Windows 7 (64-bit).

#### Issue

1. Google Chrome (34.0.1847.137) was not re-launching whenever I exit browser. When I checked running process in *Task Manger*, there is always one instance of Chrome (*chrome.exe*) running. Only when I end this process, I am able to open *Google Chrome* again.
2. When I re-installed Google Chrome from scratch, I am not able to *Sign in to to Chrome* and *sync* data. The sign in page opens with URL `chrome://chrome-signin/?source=2` and always stuck at:

   > Processing request...

   with no response. When this page is open, I cannot browse/open any web page. When I close this page, I am able to open any website.

I browsed some Google Forums and I am able to Sign in and sync my data in Google Chrome using the below link:

```
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fintl%2Fen-US%2Fchrome%2Fblank.html%3Fsource%3D3%26auto_close%3D1&service=chromiumsync&sarp=1&elo=1
```

Investigation and steps done so far:

1. Did complete scan of system using Malware tools. Found something called as "SaveSense" and removed it completely.
2. Tried to refresh user profile many times by renaming "Default" folder in `C:\Users\anurag_u\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`
3. Reinstalled *Google Chrome* completely from scratch after uninstall using *Advanced Uninstaller Pro*. I also tried installing *Google Chrome Canary* and *Chromium*. But the same issue still happens. I have deleted all the extensions from Google Chrome.
4. I have already unchecked "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" in *Advanced* menu of *Google Chrome* and have no Cloud print setup.

Any help/instructions to debug is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) or use a different user account?

Comment: This is a corporate laptop from an IT Office. When I tried clean boot, I was not able to login after restart. Error "no logon servers available". I tried login by selecting "Last Good known configuration" in F8 menu. After logon, only selective services are up as I can see in Task manager, but the Google Chrome issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

> Page opens and always stuck at *Processing request...* with no response.

This could be still relevant with recent Chrome versions and *Processing request...* can be related to variety of things. Here are some suggestions:

- Disable *Automatically detect settings* in your *Connections/LAN* settings. <sup>see: [Chrome Slow Startup](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/ol9o8cJ1sFc/4fvBPO3gK6cJ)</sup>
- Disable all extensions or test in *Incognito* mode.

  <sup>E.g. check by going to `chrome://extensions/`.</sup>
- Try clearing caches by going to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`.
- Try reinstalling browser. Also try installing [Google Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) if same is happening.
- Check your DNS servers, as it could be related to DNS lookup timeout. For example add [Google Public DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS) such as: `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.
- Disable any proxies or connected VPN.
- Try enabling or disabling IPv6 in your network adapter settings, also in your router settings.

  See this [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582954#c6) which suggest to enable IPv6:

  > I ended up solving this issue by configuring ipv6 on my network (I had ipv6 disabled on my dhcp server). It seems that a lot of extensions attempt to contact ipv6 addresses on startup. Once those addresses were able to resolve using a working ipv6 connection, all my startup delay issues went away.

  And [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582954#c9) which suggest to disable IPv6:

  > It seems just unchecking IPV6 on all of the network adapter properties solves the issue.  I'll wait a couple days to see if the work around sticks but this has been a thorn in my side for some time now.
- On Windows, try the following commands which may help:

  ```
  ipconfig /flushdns 
  nbtstat -R
  netsh winsock reset
  netsh int ipv4 reset
  netsh int ipv6 reset
  ```

  Check this [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582954#c8):

  > `netsh winsock reset` will fix it for a short amount of time.  This only seems to affect our Windows 7 computers and not our Windows 8 computers.
- Temporary disable or uninstall anti-virus, firewalls and similar.
- Try changing into different network (e.g. VPN or mobile hotspot) to see if the problem persist.

#### Debugging

- [Enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) by running *Chrome* from the command-line with `--enable-logging` or `--v=1` parameter.
- Check if anything is happening by opening [*DevTools*](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) (*Network* and *Console* tabs).
- Go to `chrome://histograms` to display stats accumulated from browser startup to previous page load (you may search for `Delay` or `Throttle` keywords).
- Use `chrome://tracing` to record and debug any processing issues, then analyse the data, especially by checking the most consuming component which web browser was stuck at.

  Here is the example:

  [image: chrome tracing, context, type FrameBlameContext, snapshot: RenderFrame, V8.Execute; translation id = 1225177025209879837 (generated_resources_*.xtb): Processing request, Je verzoek wordt verwerkt, Päringu töötlemine, Pinoproseso ang kahilingan, Päringu töötlemine, Przetwarzam żądanie, Memproses permintaan, Pinoproseso ang kahilingan, İstek işleniyor, Päringu töötlemine, Обрада захтева, 요청을 처리하는 중, Probíhá zpracování požadavku, A kérelem feldolgozása folyamatban van, Inachakata ombi, Processando solicitação, Käsitellään pyyntöä, Obdelava zahteve, Pinoproseso ang kahilingan, Elaborazione della richiesta in corso, Inachakata ombi, Je verzoek wordt verwerkt, Заявката се обработва, Memproses permintaan, Se procesează solicitarea, Inachakata ombi, A processar o pedido, Užklausa apdorojama, Pinoproseso ang kahilingan, Обробка запиту, विनंतीवर प्रक्रिया करत आहे, Notiek pieprasījuma apstrāde, Obdelava zahteve, Behandler anmodning, Đang xử lý yêu cầu, Memproses permintaan, Обработка запроса, Päringu töötlemine, Обробка запиту, Procesando la solicitud, Ihre Anfrage wird verarbeitet, Elaborazione della richiesta in corso, Obrada zahtjeva]

---

Related Google Chrome issues:

- [Issue 582954: Stuck on "processing request" when first started](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582954)
- [Issue 777121: Loading stuck at Processing Request...](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=777121)
- [Issue 363488: Browser slow to load with extensions](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=363488)

---

If none of above helps, please [the bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) with details of the issue, ideally with attached `trace_record.json.gz` file generated at `chrome://tracing` while reproducing the problem.

---

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same issue and I am somewhat hopeful I have found the solution.  This worked for me as I have not had the issue again.  I believe it has to do something with corrupted sync data on your chrome profile.  On a side-note this fix may remove all your saved bookmarks so might want export them out 1st so you can re-import when done. 
 This is what I did:

1. Close all instances of Chrome and open a single Chrome tab
2. Open Chrome Settings,  and select "Sync and Google Services"
3. Select "Data from Chrome sync"
4. From the bottom select "Reset Sync"
5. Once completed close and restart Chrome.

By doing this it will Reset sync to clear your data from the server and remove your passphrase.  Once it is completed it turns off the sync by default.  At this point it corrected my issue, I then re-enabled my sync and it still seems to be fixed.

As I said this method resolved my issue, I hope it works for you, give it a shot.